# How to use "client" in my commands? (Discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tag')
```

This error comes whenever  I try to use client in a command like this: `client.user.tag`

my `message.js` includes:

```
const client = new Client({
intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS]});
```

and

```
command.execute(client, message, args, MessageEmbed);
```

and my command file also contains: `execute(client, message, args, MessageEmbed)`

then also i am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tag')`
 a help will be really appreciated...

**UPDATE:**
Ok i just console logged the client and got this:

```
user: null,
application: null,
```

now why is the client user = null?

Comment: Hello, could you please show us a bit more code? Your error says you are trying to read someone's tag, but in code you provided - there is no `.tag`

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft yea, i tried to add it in an embed as -`.setAuthor({name: client.user.tag, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })})`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a caching issue make sure that you have not disabled user caching since this will include the client user.

Answer (score -1):

`client` is a variable that holds the Discord bot client. You should [read the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client) to learn more about how it can be used.

It seems you are trying to get the client tag. If you read the docs, you will see that the client object has a property called `user`, which holds the user object. Since user objects hold the `tag` property, you're done.

```js
client.user.tag
```

Comment: OP already said they tried to use client in a command like this: `client.user.tag`.